# Question 3(c), pg-7, Introduction to Topology and Modern Analysis, Simmons

Tags: combinatorics

The question says:
Let $U$ be a set $ \{ 1, 2, . . . , n \}$ for an arbitrary positive integer $n$. How many subsets are there? How many possible relations of the form $A \subseteq B$ are there? Can you make an informed guess as to how many of these relations are true?

Since the given set has $n$ elements, the set has $2^n$ subsets. As set inclusion is a binary relation that is partial ordered, there are total $(2^{n})^2$ relations.

Now, how should I to find out that how many are true? Even though when I have a smaller set, like $ \{ 1,2,3 \} $ I can find it out ( $ \{ 1,2,3 \} $ has $27$ true relations out of $64$ total).

Any idea how to go ahead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the subset $A$ has $k$ elements, then there are $2^{n-k}$ subsets $B$ containing $A$ (because each of the remaining $n-k$ elements can be in or out). There are ${n\choose k}$ subsets with $k$ elements, so the total number of possibilities is $\sum_{k=0}^n{n\choose k}2^{n-k}=(1+2)^n=3^n$ by the binomial theorem.

Comment: Thanks..:) Do you mean $3^n$ true relations?

Comment: @deditus yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 0):

This post is quite old, but I thought it might be useful to leave this here.

Consider the relation $A \subseteq B$. For each element $x \in U$, there are three ways in which that relation is true, namely,

1. $x \in A$ and $x \in B$
2. $x \not\in A$ and $x \in B$
3. $x \not\in A$ and $x \not \in B$.

Since there are $n$ elements, the total number of true relations is $3^n$.